# ForeignKey don't show data

Tags: python, html, sql, django, django-models

When I try to use foreignKey, html don't response

Models.py

```
class Home(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, verbose_name=(
    "book"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="book")
```

Views.py

```
def main(request):
   posts = Home.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'home/home-page.html', {'posts': posts})
```

HTML

```
{% for post in posts %} 
    {% for book in post.book.all %}
        {{ book }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` doesn't make any sense here, with a one to many relationship home only has one book, a book has many homes

so the inner for loop isn't needed, you can just use `post.book`

```
{% for post in posts %} 
    {{ post.book }}
{% endfor %}
```